# Cómo solucionar el error LoadBalancerNotFound (status code: 400) al hacer DataSource en un aws_alb, aws_lb o aws_elb

Tags: aws

Actualmente estoy ejecutando un terraform que únicamente crea el LB, la parte del RESOURCE lo crea bien, el problema lo tengo cuando quiere hacer un Data sobre el Alb, lb o Elb por si existe para no crearlo nuevamente, actualmente se me cae el terraform con un error 400 en la parte del Data

El error que retorna el terraform es este. Tengo otros módulos funcionando bajo este mismo mecanismo de usar un data para establecer el count en el Resource, pero aquí, en el Alb no me funciona. ¿Alguien sabe porque motivo me está pasando?

```
│ Error: error retrieving LB: LoadBalancerNotFound: Load balancers '[sltr-prod]' not found
│       status code: 400, request id: ad524314-474f-4c24-9410-3c246ec170c7
│
│   with module.alb.data.aws_alb.selected,
│   on .terraform/modules/alb/main.tf line 9, in data "aws_alb" "selected":
│    9: data "aws_alb" "selected" {
│
╵
ERRO[0014] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

main.tf

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "selected" {
  vpc_id = var.aws_vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.app_name}-public-subnet-*"
  }
}

data "aws_alb" "selected" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-${var.app_environment}"
}

resource "aws_alb" "application_load_balancer" {
  name               = "${var.app_name}-${var.app_environment}"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids
  security_groups    = [var.sg_id]

  tags = {
    Name             = "${var.app_name}-${var.app_environment}"
    App_name         = var.app_name
    Environment      = var.app_environment
  }

  count = data.aws_alb.selected != null ? 0 : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya tengo el problema, es porque cuándo no el data no tiene objetos, este falla

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Comment: no tengo los puntos para aprobármela xD

Comment: _Deberás esperar 48 horas para aceptar tu propia respuesta_: probablemente haya sido por el momento en que hayas intentado aceptarla, no porque no tengas reputación. Para lo que no tienes reputación suficiente aún es para comentar o dejar votos a favor, por ejemplo :)